# Template is not rendering in Angular2

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I want to render html template by giving url in Angular2, But template is not loading. I am using visual studio code editor, Below is my code and structure.

[image]

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {LoginComponent} from '../Login/login.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    // template: '<h1>Yash Employees</h1><login></login>',
    templateUrl: './app.html',
    directives: [LoginComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

template attribute is working, But templateUrl is not.

app.html contains only single line,

```
<h1>hi</h1>
```

What I need to change to resolve this?

Comment: change your `./app.html` to `./app/app.html`

Comment: Resource not found error in console, BTW, Few people have declared below line, "moduleId: module.id,", what is this ?

Comment: you will get a 404 error check properly

Comment: Yes same error :  404

Comment: you should be using `./app/component/app/app.html` for your templateUrl

Comment: "app/component/app/app.html" would work, But it is absolute URL, How to set relative one.

Comment: my first comment is the relative url

Comment: Thanks for this "./app/component/app/app.html"
 Working

Comment: I shall post that answer?

Comment: Please post it.

Comment: "app/components/app/app.html" Working,
"./app/app.html" Not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139010/discussion-between-aravind-and-keval-patel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Urls for your templateUrl properties as below,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/component/app/app.html',
    directives: [LoginComponent]
})
```

Update : As per the **[documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html)** `./filename` should work but in your case you say that it is not working I wounder.

Reference: 
[image]

Comment: That is not an absolute URL.

Comment: Though, This solved my problem, So I am accepting. But I am looking for relative URL.

Comment: you are looking for absolute URL? what do you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry, looking for relative one,
I fill , "./app/app.html" should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue because i applied guard to that route.
After removing that guard it works fine